# Does an infant under 6 months need their own ticket?

Tags: air-travel, children

I want to fly with a 5 months infant, from Johannesburg to Cape Town. Does an infant under six months need a ticket?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, every person on the aircraft needs a ticket. For one, the passenger manifest will be inaccurate if your infant is not ticketed.

However "infant without a seat" fares are typically steeply discounted (90% discount) or even free. You should investigate with the airline.

Comment: Actually some airlines do not require a ticket for an infant flying as a lap infant.  Delta for one does not on domestic flights (but does require a ticket on international flights).  Of course the adult does need to notify the airline they are traveling with a lap infant.

Answer (score 5):

If the infant is going to be held in your lap for the entire flight, then they are charged the infant rate. SAA charges about 10% of the adult fare for an infant flying domestically.

If you are bringing a car seat for the infant to use during the flight, they would need their own seat and would be charged more for the seat (child's fare).

Other carriers may have different policies, you need to check their websites for details.

Answer (score 1):

That's different for every airline but typically one adult may hold one under two year child in their lap for free.